# Xcode shortcut for showing counterpart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface

In objective-c, we look at the h file or public interface to know which can be used in public. Then see the counterpart to view the private implementation. 
In Swift, you can see what is visible to public or the interface by looking at the file counterpart.

What is the shortcut for seeing the counterpart of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Click the file then use:

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>arrow up</kbd>

Comment: Great shortcut. Thanks.